Looking for a movie set in the 1970-1980 with prisoners escaping on a train
I have seen this movie on TV about 2 or 3 years ago but it looked like it was from the 90's or so.
The film is about 2 prisoners in a cold and snowy country, one is a seasoned old man and the other is young guy who follows the old convict in his escape attempt.
They end up on a train and it somehow spins out of control. There are intermittent scenes between the control central and the prisoners on the train. The control central is trying to crash the train while they are not aware there are people in it.
They find a woman on the train as well.
In the end, the old guy detaches the lead locomotive and locks himself in it with the prison warden who came after him as they disappear into the blizzard. Leaving the young one and the woman on the slowing other part of the train.
